# Не удается установить куки тогда когда сайт открыт во фрейме на стороннем сайте

Tags: javascript, php, cookie, iframe

В чем может быть дело?

Сайт открыт во фрейме, на стороннем сайте. Пытаюсь установить куки, через js, через php.
Увы не удается, когда сайт открыт не во фрейме, то все работает на ура. В чем дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер обеспечивает приватность просмотра страниц и не принимает cookies от страниц внутри iframe. [Статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/112077/)